# I am having trouble inserting the data in the database using sequelize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js, multer

I am trying to insert the form data which contains file upload functionality in the database using sequelize, but I am only able to insert the URL or path of the specific file in the database and not the other data. My API key is working I have tested it on the Postman. Please help me out...

App.js File (Backend):

```
//set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  //rect the file
  if (file.mimetype === "application/pdf") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });

//registering
router.post("/register", upload.single("files"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  let { firstname, lastname, email, position } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  // enter new user to the database

  Gig.create({
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    position,
    files: req.file.path,
  }).then((gig) => res.json(gig));
  console
    .log("here", gig)
    .catch((err) => res.render("error", { error: err.message }));
});
```

Front end (Reactjs):

```
const newGig = {
      firstname: this.state.firstname,
      lastname: this.state.lastname,
      email: this.state.email,
      position: this.state.position,
      files: this.state.files,
    };

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("files", this.state.file);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/auth/register", fd, config, newGig)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Gig Registered");
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log()` is outside the Promise thenables.

```
  Gig.create({
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    position,
    files: req.file.path,
  })
  .then((gig) => {
     // needs to be in then() to access gig
     console.log("here", gig)
     return res.json(gig);
  )
  .catch((err) => res.render("error", {
    error: err.message
  });
```

You can also write this with async/await more concisely.

```
try {
  const git = await Gig.create({
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    position,
    files: req.file.path,
  });
  console.log("here", gig)
  return res.json(gig);
} catch (err) {
  return res.render("error", {
    error: err.message
  }
}
```

Comment: Still no luck bro I am only able to insert the file path not the other data like "firstname", "lastname"...etc. Am I making any mistake in front end ??